# Add hours to a timestamp that is formatted as a string

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe (df) that has employee start and end times formatted at strings

```
emp_id|Start|End
001|07:00:00|04:00:00
002|07:30:00|04:30:00
```

I want to add two hours to the Start and 2 hours to the End on a set of employees, not all employees.  I do this by taking a slice of the main dataframe into a separate dataframe (df2).  I then update the values and  need to merge the updated values back into the main dataframe (df1) where I will coerce back to a string, as there is a method later in the code expecting these values to be strings.

I tried doing this:

```
df1['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Start)
df1['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.End)
df2 = df1.sample(frac=0.1, replace=False, random_state=1) #takes a random 10% slice
df2['Start'] = df2['Start'] + timedelta(hours=2)
df2['End'] = df2['End'] + timedelta(hours=2)
df1.loc[df1.emp_id.isin(df2.emp_id), ['Start, 'End']] = df2[['Start', 'End']]
df1['Start'] = str(df1['Start'])
df1['End'] = str(df1['End']))
```

I'm getting a TypeError: addition/subtraction of integers and integer arrays with DateTimeArray is no longer supported.  How do I do this in Python3?

Comment: your columns start and end, do you want to handle them as *time*, i.e. if the hour exceeds 23, it starts from zero again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.applymap()` on the `Start` and `End` columns of your selected subset. Hour addition can be done by string extraction and substitution.

### Code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "emp_id": ['001', '002'],
    "Start": ['07:00:00', '07:30:00'],
    "End": ['04:00:00', '04:30:00'],
})

# a subset of employee id
set_id = set(['002'])

# locate the subset
mask = df1["emp_id"].isin(set_id)

# apply hour addition
df1.loc[mask, ["Start", "End"]] = df1.loc[mask, ["Start", "End"]].applymap(lambda el: f"{int(el[:2])+2:02}{el[2:]}")
```

### Result

```
print(df1)

  emp_id     Start       End
0    001  07:00:00  04:00:00
1    002  09:30:00  06:30:00   <- 2 hrs were added
```

Note: f-strings require python 3.6+. For earlier versions, replace the f-string with

```
"%02d%s" % (int(el[:2])+2, el[2:])
```

Note: mind corner cases (time later than 22:00) if they exist.